# Codeigniter 4 query builder results display from wrong table

Tags: query-builder, codeigniter-4

I am trying to display all the teams based on the current logged in user and the members in each team using query builder to show something like this :

```
team logo | team name        | member ign      
image     | dotatest3team_2  | dotafortest1    
                             | dotafortest2    
                             | dotafortest3    
                             | dotafortest10   
                             | dotafortest11   

image     | codtest2team     | dotafortest1    
                             | dotafortest2    
                             | dotafortest3    
                             | dotafortest10   
                             | dotafortest11
```

Somehow the result I have gotten :

1. It only display 1 team "codtest2team"
2. It display 6 members(which I think it is pulling from the add_game table records) instead of 5 members(from teammember_list table)

I have include my database [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a49e2)

Below are my current code:

Model

```
return $this->db->table('team_list t1')
            ->join('teammember_list t2', 't2.team_id = t1.team_id')
            ->join('add_game t3', 't3.game_id = t2.game_id')
            ->join('game_list t4', 't4.game_id = t3.game_id')
            ->where('t2.user_id', $user_id)
            ->get()
            ->getResultArray();
```

View

```
<table class="table teams-list">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Logo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Members IGN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

        
<?php

$team_array = array();
foreach ($teams as $row) {
    // Set title value
    $team = $row['team_id'];
    // Check if team value has already been used, proceed if not
    if(!in_array($team, $team_array)) {
    // Add team value to $team_array and echo team
    $team_array[] = $team;

?>

<tr>
                <th scope="row"><img src="<?php echo base_url('/public/uploads/img/'. strtolower($row['team_logo'])); ?>" alt="" /></th>
                <td><?= $row['team_name']; ?></td>
                
                
                <td>

<?php

    foreach ($teams as $row) {
        if($team == $row['team_id']) {

?>
<?= $row['ign']; ?>

<?php
        }
    }
?>
</td>
</tr>

<?php

    }
}

?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I can't find what and where is wrong. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I've a fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a49e2/26, it explains each step, but I think your database misses the members of each team, please update!

Comment: @Vickel Can you elaborate "members of each team"? Or is it the way I structure my table is wrong? Because I have tag the members under teammember_list table with a team_id.